# TypeError when converting dictionary to JSON array

Tags: python, json, dictionary

How do I take a python dictionary where the keys and values are Strings and convert it into a JSON String.

This is what I have right now:

```
import json

def create_simple_meeting(subject, startDate, endDate, location, body):
    info = dict()
    if(subject != ""):
        info["subject"] = subject
    if(startDate != ""):
        info["startDate"] = startDate
    if(endDate != ""):
        info["endDate"] = endDate
    if(body != ""):
        info["body"] = body
    if(location != ""):
        info["location"] = location
    print(json.dumps(dict))

create_simple_meeting("This is the subject of our meeting.","2014-05-29 11:00:00","2014-05-29 12:00:00", "Boca Raton", "We should definitely meet up, man")
```

And it gives me this error

```
  File "/Users/bens/Documents/workspace/Copy of ws1 for py java playing/opias/robot/libs/playing.py", line 15, in create_simple_meeting
    print(json.dumps(dict))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 243, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <type 'dict'> is not JSON serializable
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You are trying to serialise the *type* object, `dict`, instead of `info`. Dump the right variable:

```
print(json.dumps(info))
```