# OAuth2 service account credentials for Google Drive upload script

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-oauth

Apologies in advance if anyone has asked this before, but I've got some basic questions about a server-side Python script I'm writing that does a nightly upload of CSV files to a folder in our Google Drive account.  The folder owner has created a Google API project, enabled the Drive API for this and created a credentials object which I've downloaded as a JSON file.  The folder has been shared with the service account email, so I assume that the script will now have access to this folder, once it is authorized.

The JSON file contains the following fields `private_key_id`, `private_key`, `client_email`, `client_id`, `auth_uri`, `token_uri`, `auth_provider_x509_cert_url`, `client_x509_cert_url`.

1. I'm guessing that my script will not need all of these - which are the essential or compulsory fields for OAuth2 authorization?
2. The example Python script given here

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/python

seems to assume that the credentials are retrieved directly from a JSON file:

```
...
home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
    os.makedirs(credential_dir)
credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                               'drive-python-quickstart.json')

store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
credentials = store.get()
...
```

but in our setup we are storing them in our own DB and the script accesses them via a dict. How would the authorization be done if the credentials were in a dict?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests example code in google documentation

Answer (score 2):

After browsing the source code, it seems that it was designed to accept only JSON files. They are using [simplejson](https://simplejson.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#) to encode and decode. Take a look at the source code:

[This](http://google-api-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/docs/epy/oauth2client.file-pysrc.html#Storage.__init__) is where is gets the content from the file you provide:

```
 62 def locked_get(self): 
 63      """Retrieve Credential from file. 
 64   
 65      Returns: 
 66        oauth2client.client.Credentials 
 67   
 68      Raises: 
 69        CredentialsFileSymbolicLinkError if the file is a symbolic link. 
 70      """ 
 71      credentials = None 
 72      self._validate_file() 
 73      try: 
 74        f = open(self._filename, 'rb') 
 75        content = f.read() 
 76        f.close() 
 77      except IOError: 
 78        return credentials 
 79   
 80      try: 
 81        credentials = Credentials.new_from_json(content) #<----!!!
 82        credentials.set_store(self) 
 83      except ValueError: 
 84        pass 
 85   
 86      return credentials
```

In [new_from_json](http://google-api-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/docs/epy/oauth2client.client-pysrc.html#Credentials.new_from_json) they attempt to decode the content using simplejson.

```
 205 def new_from_json(cls, s): 
 206      """Utility class method to instantiate a Credentials subclass from a JSON 
 207      representation produced by to_json(). 
 208   
 209      Args: 
 210        s: string, JSON from to_json(). 
 211   
 212      Returns: 
 213        An instance of the subclass of Credentials that was serialized with 
 214        to_json(). 
 215      """ 
 216      data = simplejson.loads(s)
```

Long story short, it seems you'll have to construct a JSON file from your dict. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23956353/convert-python-dict-to-json-string). Basically, you'll need to `json.dumps(your_dictionary)` and create a file.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it looks like a `SignedJwtAssertionCredentials` may be one answer.  Another possibly is

```
from oauth2client import service_account
...
credentials = service_account._ServiceAccountCredentials(
      service_account_id=client.clid,
      service_account_email=client.email,
      private_key_id=client.private_key_id,
      private_key_pkcs8_text=client.private_key,
      scopes=client.auth_scopes,
)
....
```

Comment: SignedJwtAssertionCredentials has been [removed from oauth2client](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/issues/401)